# Is it possible to add new columns to DataFrame in Pandas (python)?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

Consider the following code:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

todays_date = datetime.datetime.now().date()
index = pd.date_range(todays_date-datetime.timedelta(10), periods=10, freq='D')

columns = ['A','B', 'C']
df_ = pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=columns)
df_ = df_.fillna(0) # with 0s rather than NaNs
data = np.array([np.arange(10)]*3).T
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=columns)
df
```

Here we create an empty DataFrame in Python using Pandas and then fill it to any extent. However, is it possible to add columns dynamically in a similar manner, i.e., for columns = ['A','B', 'C'], it must be possible to add columns D,E,F etc till a specified number.

Comment: It's unclear what your question is here, you can dynamically add columns at will, the only advantage to defining the columns up front would be for space reasons, you can easily do something like `for col in col_list: df[col] = some_vals`

Comment: Suppose the columns correspond to parameters. Then if we specify how much parameters we require only dynamically, then we will not be able to specify number of columns in the code. In that case, what needs to be done?

Comment: Sorry you're going to have to edit your question with a concrete example, what you are describing sounds like a design issue that is not specific to pandas

Comment: The problem is simple. I have a text file that gets populated upon runtime, each time with different number of rows and columns. I want to plot a scatterplot matrix based on that text file data. For that I am using DataFrames.

Comment: So what's your problem? the df will be created with the correct number of columns but with names starting from `0` onwards. Are you asking about dynamically assigning column names? It's terribly unclear to me your question

Comment: So is it enough if I don't specify    columns = ['A','B', 'C']  ?

Comment: That is correct your df will always have index and column labels, but if you don't specify them or if your data does not possess index or column label information then the df will generate it's own using integer labels so `0...N`

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite follow either; if you loaded multiple text files into different frames and needed to concatenate, my answer might help. But the structuring of the frame loaded from a csv is handled by the reader as @EdChum pointed out.

Comment: @EdChum that was my doubt (if df would generate its own lables). Thanks a lot

Comment: admittedly your plot labels will not look pretty and it is probably better to assign column labels so that your plot labels look nicer but basically it is not necessary to specify the column labels

Answer (score 0):

I think the

> pandas.DataFrame.append

method is what you are after.

e.g.

```
output_frame=input_frame.append(appended_frame)
```

There are additional examples in the documentation [Pandas merge join and concatenate documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html)

Comment: import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv("test.txt",delim_whitespace=True,header=None)

Comment: I was thinking you wanted to compose your additional columns into another frame then concatenate the old and new frames, but maybe that's not quite what you want?

Comment: pd.read_csv("t.txt",delim_whitespace=True,header=None) here is it possible to readthis text file as input to dataframe? (in this case the text file can have as many columns as needed)

Comment: @hari but in that case the csv reader can deduce the number of columns, when you create a df it can also deduce the number of required columns based on the type of data you pass, you don't have to specify the columns at all for instance if you pass a dict